# How to fix dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib

Tags: lib, dyld

i'm using HiC-Pro mapping program on macOS Catalina. When it's running the log says:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda3/bin/bowtie2-align-s
  Reason: image not found
(ERR): Description of arguments failed!
Exiting now ...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this library not loaded error message?

Answer (score 0):

I just started getting this error, as well -- environments I had installed just a couple weeks ago that included Bowtie2 still work, but when I install a new environment with the same Conda yaml file today it is no longer working, with this same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `tbb` through

```sh
brew install tbb
```

This fixed the error for me for a different binary that threw the same error.